# Python: Set it into a table format

Tags: python, tabular

I'm wondering how to make my function output into a table format. 
Here's my code:

```
def calculation(limit):
   limit = int(limit)
   result = 0

    for line in range (1, limit+1):
        print ("\t")
        for num in range (1, limit+1):
            result = line * num
            print (result, sep='')
```

The question is the output right now are like vertically:

10

20

30

40

50

60

70

80

90

100

110

120

And I would like to convert it into this format:

10 11

20 22

30 33

40 44

50 55

60 66

70 77

80 88

90 99

100 110

110 121

120 132

Comment: Please clarify the sample output. The code should not produce the output you claim. Rather it should print a bunch of vertical lines. What is your expected change in that output?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to print `line`, `num`, and `result` on the same line of output. You should use a single print statement:

```
limit=3
for line in range (1, limit+1):
    for num in range (1, limit+1):
        result = line * num
        print(line, num, result, sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
1   1   1
1   2   2
1   3   3
2   1   2
2   2   4
2   3   6
3   1   3
3   2   6
3   3   9
```